# Why click button and client post doubling link api to server

Tags: angular, typescript

server post

```
     GetListNickNameByNameAndID(name:string,id:string):Promise<any>{
   //send api link to server
    return this._http.post(this.apiUrlgetNick+'?userName='+name+'&serverId='+id,{headers:new JsonHeaders()})
    .map((response:Response) => response.json()).toPromise();
}
```

call server post in Component

```
    checkApi(){       
    this.getItemService.GetListNickNameByNameAndID('admin','1').then((respone:any)=>{
        console.log(respone);
    })

}
```

code html

```
    <button (click)="checkApi()" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Check</button>
```

result: 
[image: post doubling link api]

Comment: So what is your question here?

p.s. this behavior is desired, as 1st call is with "Request Method:OPTIONS" and second call is with "Request Method:POST".
this is how post requests works, 1st call is to ensure your authenticity with cookies and session id.

Comment: This is first times I ask in stakoverflow. I was edit my question. Thanks

Comment: after edit, still i didn't see your question. but I answered in previous comment what I get form form your question statement.

Comment: The question is in the title and you answered it